# How to propagate Sleuth Trace Id to EurekaHttpClient?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

Currently, I am working on my company's microservices solution which uses **Spring Cloud Edgware.SR1**. This solution includes the following main flavors:
`api-gateway(Zuul)`, `service-discovery(Eureka)`, `uaa`, `zipkin-server` and `business logic` services.

I am trying to provide a good tracing for all requests in our system. In Zipkin UI I can see a trace for the request that starts in api-gateway, going through uaa to our business logic service. But requests to the Eureka are missing in the trace. Instead, there is a separate trace with a single span for `service-discovery` endpoint `http://eureka/apps/**`.

I had the same issue with `uaa` request to `http://user/` endpoint and solved it by adding `TraceRestTemplateInterceptor` to our Oauth2 client.
However, I found it difficult to override `EurekaHttpClient` and add the mentioned interceptor.

Is there any other way to propagate trace id to Eureka Clients?

Comment: We never intended to instrument Eureka as such (maybe I misunderstand your question). If you register apps in Eureka and you use a `FeignClient` or `RestTemplate`, then there's nothing else you need to do. Try upgrading to `SR3` and see if things are still wrong?

Comment: The eureka client is never part of a trace. All of its work happens on another thread

Comment: Even when Zuul gets a list of instances from Eureka? I thought it should be synchronous actions.